# Cannot add primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported an excel file with the data I need into Sql Server. Now I want to add a primary key using this statement:

```
alter table Tickets add constraint idTicket primary key (TOC);;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'Tickets'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I looked but couldn't find a solution here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Per the message, a primary key must be non-`NULL` and the column must therefore also be defined as such. `TOC` will need to be altered to be non-`NULL` (the statement for this depends on the type of `TOC`).

Comment: Just usually means one of your columns (idTicket) allows nulls which cannot be for a primary key, just go to the table design and uncheck the allow nulls box on the column you wish to make the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Tickets
ALTER TOC INT NOT NULL
GO
```

Then do your query to add the primary key

Comment: would you know how to delete duplicate values in my table cause i need to delete those rows and keep my table only with unique values

Comment: @RagingDeathWish: That's [another question altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/4137916).

Comment: [everybody, in chorus] "That's another question."

Comment: \*/me slaps @Brian with a large trout\*